# Find sufficient and necessary conditions on the variable $t$ such that the interval $I$ contain at least one prime numbrer

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Find sufficient and necessary conditions on the variable $t$ such that the interval $$I=(((ln(t))/(ln2)),((ln(1+t))/(ln2)))$$ contain at least one **prime numbrer**. I thought about some konwn bounds on prime numbers such as the well known result of Ingham that there is a constant $K$ such that for $x≥1$ there is a prime $p$ satisfying
$$x<p<x+Kx^{(5/8)}$$

and the fact that there is at least one prime between $x³$ and $(x+1)³$ for every $x≥10⁶⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰⁰$. However, I am not able to use these facts to prove my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with known bounds on prime numbers. Suppose $p$ lies in that interval. Then

\begin{align}
&& \frac{\ln t}{\ln 2} &< p < \frac{\ln (1+t)}{\ln 2}\\
&\iff & \ln t &< p\ln 2 < \ln (1+t)\\
&\iff& t &< 2^p < 1+t\\
&\iff & 2^p-1 &< t < 2^p.
\end{align}